# Socket connection disconnects from node server after sending first message

Tags: angular, typescript, sockets, socket.io

I'm using angular as client side and node.js for server side sockets connection.

> Created connection :

```
setupSocketConnection() {
    this.socket = io(SOCKET_ENDPOINT);
    
  }

public sendMessage(message:any) {
  this.socket.emit('sendMessage', message);
}
```

but as i click on send button this `sendMessage` method is called i get this error and server is shut down

```
index.js:40
    callback();
    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\..server\index.js:40:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at C:\...\server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:531:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

> link:

```
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-manage-users-in-socket-io-in-node-js/
```

> Node.js Script

```
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const { addUser, removeUser, getUser,
        getUsersInRoom } = require("./users");
 
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);
app.use(cors())
 
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on('join', ({ name, room }, callback) => {
 
        const { error, user } = addUser(
            { id: socket.id, name, room });
 
        if (error) return callback(error);
 
        // Emit will send message to the user
        // who had joined
        socket.emit('message', { user: 'admin', text:
            `${user.name},
            welcome to room ${user.room}.` });
 
        // Broadcast will send message to everyone
        // in the room except the joined user
        socket.broadcast.to(user.room)
            .emit('message', { user: "admin",
            text: `${user.name}, has joined` });
 
        socket.join(user.room);
 
        io.to(user.room).emit('roomData', {
            room: user.room,
            users: getUsersInRoom(user.room)
        });
        callback();
    })
 
    socket.on('sendMessage', (message, callback) => {
 
        const user = getUser(socket.id);
        io.to(user.room).emit('message',
            { user: user.name, text: message });
 
        io.to(user.room).emit('roomData', {
            room: user.room,
            users: getUsersInRoom(user.room)
        });
        callback();
    })
 
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        const user = removeUser(socket.id);
        if (user) {
            io.to(user.room).emit('message',
            { user: 'admin', text:
            `${user.name} had left` });
        }
    })
 
})
 
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000,
    () => console.log(`Server has started.`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try emitting your event like this

```
this.socket.emit("sendMessage", message, (resp) => {
  });
```